# Bootstrap ViewPort

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im using bootstrap 3.0 rtl Version . i make it 12 column , it was so great when i was test the responsive layout in the Firefox ( Resize the screen ). the probelm show when i test it from the phone . the website is show like desktop version ?? why its not change to responsive look , i think the problem with `Viewport` or something like that ? try it [Mysite](http://mohammadsamy.com/Goejaza/index.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official bootstrap **viewport**  Insert this code before title start

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Reference:- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 2):

> You just need to add meta to tag, bootstrap wont works fine without this meta tag

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp